# How to determine environment in a component?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using the`vue-cli 2.8.1` with a full-featured webpack template. I have a component that needs access to the environment variable in order to display different content for either `dev` or `prod` environments. How would you get access to this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier than I thought.

One can access the env variable from anywhere in the app code.

`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) //production || development`